# What is a generalized stochastic process? I've found two different definitions. Are they equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, distribution-theory, stochastic-analysis

Let $\mathcal D:=C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ and $\mathcal D'$ be the dual space of $\mathcal D$.

> What is a generalized stochastic process? I've found two different definitions in some textbooks:
>
> 1. A stochastic process $(\xi_\varphi)_{\varphi\in\mathcal D}$. But where does $\xi$ take its values? In $\mathbb R$?
> 2. A $\mathcal D'$-valued random variable

Are these definitions somehow equivalent? Moreover, which topology on $\mathcal D$ do they assume? Without specifying this topology, we can't even talk about $\mathcal D'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed compact $K \subset \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^d$, we topologize $C^\infty(K)$ by the semi-norms 
$$ \|u\|_{\alpha,K} := \sup_{x \in K} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\abs{D^\alpha u(x)}, \qquad \alpha \in \def\N{\mathbf N}\N^d $$
The usual topology on $\def\D{\mathcal D}\D := C^\infty_c(\R^d)$ is the direct limit topology of the $C^\infty(K)$, that is the largest topology that makes all inclusion maps $\D \to C^\infty(K)$, continuous.

Given a $\D'$-valued random variable $X \colon \Omega \to \D'$, for each $\phi \in D$, we have a $\def\C{\mathbf C}\C$-valued variable $\xi_\phi := \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<\phi, X(-)> \colon \Omega \to \C$. But note, that the $\xi$'s which arrise like that have some special properties, both algebraic, e. g. $$ \xi_\phi + \xi_\psi = \xi_{\phi + \psi} $$ and analytic, e. g. 
$$ \phi_n \to \phi \implies \xi_{\phi_n} \to \xi_\phi $$
$(\xi_\phi)$ without these properties cannot be respresented as an $\D'$-valued random variable.

Comment: So, the usual definition should be $(2.)$, right? From $(2.)$ it's clear, that $(\xi_\varphi)_{\varphi\in\mathcal D}$ is a stochastic process (with some special properties you've mentioned). It should be a real-valued (not $\mathcal C$-valued) process, since the elements of $\mathcal D$ are real-valued.

Comment: Now, I've got a better understanding of the relationship between $(1.)$ and $(2.)$. Thank you very much. However, I've got another question related to the choice of the topology on $\mathcal D$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629116/given-a-c-c%E2%88%9Eg-valued-random-variable-is-c-c%E2%88%9Eg%E2%88%8B%CF%86%E2%86%A6-text-e-langle-xi-%CF%86-r

Comment: I don't think the definition of the topology of $\mathcal{D}$ in this answer is correct. From (2) it is trivial to construct (1). However, one can go from (1) to (2) by an analogue of the Kolmogov continuity Thm. The best treatment is Xavier Fernique's thesis (in French) https://aif.centre-mersenne.org/item/AIF_1967__17_1_1_0/