# Are linear and continuous mappings between locally convex vector spaces bounded?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, operator-theory

I know that continuity and boundedness of linear mappings between normed vector spaces are equivalent, but does the same hold true for locally convex vector spaces? If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: What does it mean for a map of TVSes to be bounded?

Comment: @MikeMiller I've updated the question cause I'm primary interested in locally convex vector spaces. However, there is a notion of boundedness in topological vector spaces, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_%28topological_vector_space%29

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes - let's see if I can prove it. First we need to define "bounded".

Recall that $S\subset X$ is said to be bounded if for every open set $V$ containing the origin there exists $c>0$ so that $S\subset cV$.

Now given two topological vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ we say that $T:X\to Y$ is bounded if $T(S)$ is bounded in $Y$ for every bounded $S\subset S$.

Say $T:X\to Y$ is linear and continuous. Say $S\subset X$ is bounded; we need too show that $T(S)$ is bounded in $Y$. So say $V$ is a neighborhood of the origin in $Y$. Let $W=T^{-1}(V)$. Since $S$ is bounded there exists $c>0$ with $S\subset cW$. So $T(S)\subset T(cW)=cT(W)\subset cV$. Sure enough, $T$ is bounded.

Offhand I don't see how to prove the converse in general. But in locally convex spaces it must be easy. Say the topology on $X$ is defined by a family of seminorms $A$. Then $S\subset X$ is bounded if and only if every $\rho\in A$ is bounded on $S$. It follows that if the topology on $Y$ is defined by a family of seminorms $B$, then the linear map $T :X\to Y$ is bounded if and only if for every $\rho\in B$ there exist $\rho_1,\dots,\rho_n\in A$ with $$\rho(Tx)\le c\sum_{j=1}^n\rho_j(x).$$ It's easy to see that that condition implies that $T$ is continuous.

Comment: So, at least for locally convex vector spaces we have the desired equivalence. This question arose in me while thinking about the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629116/given-a-c-c%E2%88%9Eg-valued-random-variable-is-c-c%E2%88%9Eg%E2%88%8B%CF%86%E2%86%A6-text-e-langle-xi-%CF%86-r. After your very helpful answer here, you might be able to answer that question, too.

Comment: I don't understand why you write "it's easy to see that this condition implies $T$ is continuous" when the entire argument follows from "if and only if" relationships?